# Simplify php form validation - two files into one?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

My php and javascript knowledge are limited. I am taking a class :)

I have a form that checks to see that fields aren't empty; if they are an alert appears.  A second php file then checks the submitted form to see that the email and phone number fit parameters; if they don't then the form is not submitted and an error appears on a new page.
Is there a way to combine the two?

Here is the code on the contact.php:

```
<script>
    function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["contactform"]["companyname"].value;
    var y=document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
    var z=document.forms["contactform"]["telephone"].value;
    var e=document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("company name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
      if (y==null || y=="")
      {
      alert("name must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
      if (z==null || z=="")
      {
      alert("telephone must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
      if (e==null || e=="") 
      {
      alert("email must be filled out");
      return false;
      }
    //send
    alert("Form sent."); 
    document.contactform.submit();  
    }
  </script>
```

In the second send_form_email.php:

```
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email'])) 
        {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $companyname = $_POST['companyname']; // required
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // not required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp =  '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
   $string_exp = "/^[0-9.'-]+$/";


  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$telephone)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Phone Number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
```

Comment: I seriously don't see why this was put on hold, or even downvoted. This is a perfectly good question... I don't see why some users are so mean as to act like this without even leaving a comment on how to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make a jQuery validation:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

and trim and mysql escape chars before entering info in DB or sending by email.
(PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php )

Basically, you can do all your verification client side using jQuery Validation plugin.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking to provide a more user friendly experience than the form I have currently have. Your form is much better. :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like jqueryForms (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) do submit the page via ajax and do all the validation in PHP, the advantage to this is that if I need to check if an emial address is in use or want to run some advanced server side/database driven check on the data I can, then I have it return a json object that a script then will use to toss up an error and highlight fields and the such. Added bonus is that since I have all this done already with jqueryForms I can just go a head and do the entire form via ajax and provide a smooth experience for the user.

I't s a more complicated solution that your probably looking for (and depending on your experience you may have to read up a bit when implementing) but it gives you only one place to worry about verification and doesn't force the user to wait for a reload just to learn that the information the submitted wont work (and bonus points, if there submitting a for that includes a password or captcha they wont have to re-type it).